# Web scraping from the span element

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am on a scraping project and I am lookin to scrape from the following.

```
<div class="spec-subcat attributes-religion">
<span class="h5">Faith:</span>
<span>Christian</span>
<span>Islam</span>
</div>
```

I want to extract only Christian, Islam as the output.(Without the 'Faith:').

This is my try:

```
faithdiv = soup.find('div', class_='spec-subcat attributes-religion')
faith = faithdiv.find('span').text.strip()
```

How can I make this done?

Comment: get the span of class h5 as element and then use next on that element. you need to have a fixed point to get to <span> Christian </span>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways you can fix this, I would suggest the following - Find all `<span>` in `<div>` that have not the `class="h5"`:

```
soup.select('div.spec-subcat.attributes-religion span:not(.h5)')
```

#### Example

```
import requests

html_text = '''
<div class="spec-subcat attributes-religion">
<span class="h5">Faith:</span>
<span>Christian</span>
<span>Islam</span>
</div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')

', '.join([x.get_text() for x in soup.select('div.spec-subcat.attributes-religion span:not(.h5)')])
```

#### Output

```
Christian, Islam
```